# How to screen cast Qt app on ios & android

Tags: qt, chromecast, screencast

I have Qt 5.6 app which works on nicely on both iOS & Android. I want to add a screen cast feature to my Qt app.

**How can I add Chromecast capability to my app?**
Are there any better solutions I should use to make it work on both iOS & Android?

Comment: @Tim Cooper thanks for editing. tough to get a response on anything related to Qt.